# SQL Query always fails

Tags: php, post, mysqli, sql-update

I'm having some trouble with a php script I have.

```
if(!empty($_POST['iblogtitle']))
{
    $ptitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['iblogtitle']);
    $pcontent = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['iblogcontent']);
    $pblogid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['iblogid']);
    $query = "UPDATE blog SET PostTitle='" . $ptitle . "', PostContent='" . $pcontent . "', PostDate=NOW() WHERE PostID='" . $pblogid . "'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if($sql)
    {
        header("LOCATION: blog.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $result = "Blog update failed: " . mysqli_error($link) . " / " . $query;
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when this `if` statement is entered, clearly `$_POST['iblogtitle']` MUST have a value. However, I have checked and re-checked and even changed the `$query` to not include `mysqli_real_escape_string` values and EVERY single time I get a failed update.

**Error recieved:**

`Blog update failed: / UPDATE blog SET PostTitle='', PostContent='', PostDate=NOW() WHERE PostID=''`

There is no actual MySQL error. I have made sure error_reporting is turned off and even set it to `error_reporting(1)` just above the variable declaration.

Comment: Could you echo the `$query`?

Comment: @silkfire he's already doing that

Comment: `"I have made sure error_reporting is turned off "` **that's what you did wrong.** `error_reporting(E_ALL);` it have to be

Comment: Have you verified that the $link is valid?

Comment: which type of field is  "PostDate"

Comment: Sorry I did mean on, I have no idea why I wrote off¬ Nonetheless, with error_reporting(E_ALL) I get the same error message as I posted earlier.

Comment: PostDate is a DATETIME field, $_POST['iblogid'] can't be empty, otherwise the I wouldn't be getting an error message.

Comment: Could you try echo the error number? `mysqli_errno($link)`

Comment: so you have to make errors appear on screen if you want to see them on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the script in total so I can take a look.

Sometimes $link may be invalid because you forgot to include the connection sounds stupid is the truth.

Comment: I have actually just included my "base.php" which includes my connection details and everything works fine. My only query now is that I can't understand why this didn't work. The script I've shown you guys works like this:

`blog.php > if $_GET['blogid']=x > include "blogedit.php"`

blog.php ALREADY includes base.php

So why didn't it pull over?

Comment: Probably because of the parameters because its kinda weird to include in a include in a include or towards that direction.

so if im correct everything is working now?

Comment: Figured it out! I was including header.php, which includes base.php in the if statement BELOW the one that includes the script above. Ergo, the header was never called and nor was base. $link didn't exist!

Comment: Everything is fine, thanks Tredged and everyone else that helped!

Comment: Yea its common problem thats why I said include in a include in a include isnt good.